Umformulierung von Vorgangspassiv in Zustandspassiv
Kann man den Satz:

... auf dem ökologische Konzepte prämiert wurden

auch im Zustandspassiv formulieren?
Wenn ja, welcher Satz ist richtig?

Das ist kein vollständiger Satz, sondern ein Nebensatz.

@RHa: Wie wäre es mit: "Der Ölkongress, auf dem ökologische Konzepte prämiert wurden, endete im Tumult."

Wie die Namen schon sagen, beschreibt das Vorgangspassiv Vorgänge, das Zustandspassiv Zustände. Das Prämieren von irgendwas ist ein Vorgang. Natürlich kann man den Zustand des Prämiertseins in einen Satz packen, aber der sagt dann halt was anderes aus. Das ist keine "Umformulierung", sondern ein anderer Satz mit einer anderen Aussage.

Ich mache daraus mal einen richtigen (Haupt-)Satz:

Die ökologischen Konzepte wurden prämiert.

Das ist Vorgangspassiv Präteritum. Im Präsens sieht das so aus. (Der Vorgang findet jetzt statt):

Die ökologischen Konzepte werden prämiert.

Wenn man sagen will, dass die Konzepte jetzt in einem bestimmten Zustand sind, muss man den Zustandspassiv Präsens verwenden:

Die ökologischen Konzepte sind prämiert.

Wir haben es also jetzt mit prämierten Konzepten zu tun. Man kann den Zustandspassiv natürlich auch im Präteritum bilden:

Die ökologischen Konzepte waren prämiert.

Eine Eigenheit des Präteritum ist aber die folgende: Wenn ein Zustand im Präteritum formuliert wird, macht man damit ausdrücklich kenntlich, dass dieser Zustand nur in der Vergangenheit vorgelegen hat, aber in der Gegenwart ist das nicht mehr der Fall.

Präsens:

Karl wohnt seit 1985 in Wien.

Das heißt, dass Karl in Jahr 1985 in Wien gewohnt hat, und auch 1986 und 1987 usw., und es heißt ausdrücklich auch, dass er auch heute noch in Wien wohnt.

Präteritum

Karl wohnte in Wien.

Das bedeutet, dass er früher mal in Wien daheim war, jetzt aber nicht mehr.


Auf das prämierte Konzept angewandt folgt das daraus:

Die ökologischen Konzepte waren prämiert.

Das ist Zustandspassiv Präteritum, aber die Aussage ist eben, dass die Konzepte früher mal prämiert waren, und dass danach diese Prämierung wieder zurückgenommen wurde, so dass man diese Konzepte heute nicht mehr als prämierte Konzepte bezeichnen kann. Eine Situation, in der man genau das sagen will, ist bei einer Prämierung nur schwer vorstellbar, daher klingt der Zustandspassiv hier ein wenig seltsam. In anderen Konstellationen ist aber auch ein Zustandspassiv im Präteritum möglich:

Lisas Zimmer war zu Mittag noch sauber aufgeräumt. Aber du kannst dir nicht vorstellen, wie es jetzt, am Abend wieder aussieht.


Das Vorgangspassiv spricht über etwas, das passiert (einen Vorgang):

Unsere ökologischen Konzepte wurden auf der Konferenz prämiert.

Das Zustandspassiv spricht über etwas, das ist (einen Zustand):

Unsere ökologischen Konzepte sind prämiert.

Das heißt, man kann den Nebensatz natürlich grammatisch durchaus ins Zustandspassiv bringen, aber man ändert damit den Sinn, und welcher Satz "richtig" ist, hängt davon ab, was er aussagen soll.
Beide folgenden Sätze sind richtig, aber der zweite ist etwas konstruiert. Ökologische Konzepte können prämiert sein, aber sie sind normalerweise nicht auf etwas prämiert.

Wir besuchten einen Kongress, auf dem ökologische Konzepte prämiert wurden.


In der Ausstellung hängt ein Poster, auf dem ökologische Konzepte prämiert sind.


Der zweite Satz ist jedenfalls mehr als diskutabel: "auf einem Poster prämiert" ist kein Zustand, den es wirklich gibt. Dinge sind entweder prämiert oder nicht und die prämierten können auf einem Poster verzeichnet sein oder dgl..

@bakunin Ja, das ist natürlich eine verkürzte Ausdrucksweise, aber durchaus verständlich. Mir fiel kein besseres Beispiel ein, aber zu der Aussage, dass der Nebensatz aus der Frage im Zustandspassiv nicht möglich ist, möchte ich mich nicht versteigen.

Ersetze "wurden" durch "waren".
